# Compute a list of files in folder except for certain ones in bash

Tags: bash

I have a bash script running an executable against a bunch of test files in a folder. Some of the test files should pass, and some should fail. What I want to do is make a list of files that should fail, and then treat the rest of the tests in the folder as positive tests. Then, I can iterate over each list separately and handle the result accordingly.

This is what I had, which works when there is only 1 failure test, but doesn't work for more:

```
negative_tests() {
    echo "../testcases/test3.txt"
    echo "../testcases/test4.txt"
}
negative_tests=$(negative_tests)

positive_tests=$(comm -23 <(ls ../testcases/*) <(negative_tests))

log "Running tests.."
for testfile in $positive_tests; do
    ./a.out $testfile >> output.txt || { echo "Failed on $testfile." ; exit 1; }
done

for testfile in $negative_tests; do
    ./a.out $testfile >> output.txt && { echo "Succeeded on $testfile succeeded when failure was expected."; exit 1; }
done
```

I have a feeling I'm just missing something with how bash's data model works. Any ideas or better ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this approach works, but the way `comm` works is that it expects the lines it diffs to be in order. So, I needed to pipe the negative cases into `sort` so they'd match the order of files in `ls`:

```
positive_tests=$(comm -23 <(ls ../testcases/*) <(negative_tests | sort))
```

Then, everything works as expected. Though I'd be interested in seeing any other solutions people might have.